# Caching portions of page in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

At **//Build/2016**, **Daniel Roth**, during [ASP.NET Core Deep Dive into MVC](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B812) talked about *TagHelpers* and showed [Cache TagHelper](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1552).
This tag, among other things, allow to cache several portions of the page.

In my project (MVC5) i need to cache some pages, but i can't cache all the page, because in Layout View i have some data about users that can't be cached.

Here is an example of what i need to do:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--- Head code ---->
    <head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">

            <!--- This shouldn't be cached ---->
            <div id="top-menu">
                <!--- User Data ---->
            </div>

            <!--- This should be cached ---->
            <div id="page-content">
                <!--- Page Data ---->
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

There's a way to do something like this even in MVC5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick read through of that, it sounds like you need Donut Caching.  This is a method of providing caching for portions of a page rather than all of it.

If you have separated your partials into actions, you can use the outputcache directive to cache these so they aren't executed each time.

Here is a good write up on the technique:

http://www.adamriddick.com/2013/06/asp-net-mvc4-donut-caching-donut-hole-caching/

Quite an old article, however, I believe the technique still holds water.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had read an article about this technique, but wasn't very clear and i thought that it was not the right solution.
This article is more clear, and now I understand how implementare this solution in my project.